# Configuring softphone for asterisk - PBX

Tags: asterisk, voip, ivr, pbx

I've been trying to configure my softphone (twinkle) to work with asterisk for many days now and to no avail. I'm running both asterisk and the softphone in linux on a virtual machine.

My sip.conf file looks like this:

```
[general]
context=default
allowoverlap=no
bindport=5060
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
srvlookup=yes

[1000]
type=friend
context=phones
host=dynamic
username=1000
```

In the twinkle account settings, I have username:1000, domain: localhost

This gives me the error 403 forbidden. Can you please please help me figure out how to fix this? I'm running the softphone on a different sip port from asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is probably super weak but it will something for you to try before someone will help you with a good advice.

First of all: anytime I create a VM with Asterisk to make some tests or new IVRs I always have issues with a firewall. Check if your firewall is on or off on your linux box since it can be an issue. You have to turn it off or make a proper setup for it.

Secondly:
I look at my sip configurations and they look just like yours but I always specify secret=some_password and host=dynamic. You might also want to try to add a port setting for your user if you say that softphone is on a different sip port from asterisk. but 5060 is a regular port for sip. More info on sip.conf [INFO sip.conf](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+sip.conf)

Also check what SIP Phone you are using. Some non-popular ones could have some issues during setting. I would advise you to try eyeBeam for Windows or Ekiga for Linux should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try sip.conf:

```
[general]
context=default
allowoverlap=no
bindport=5060
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
srvlookup=yes

[1000]
type=friend
context=phones
host=dynamic
username=1000
secret=1000
```

And client try:
username: 1000
pass: 1000
domain: ip_of_asterisk_server

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me before. All I did was change Twinkle's configuration to use port 5061.  Check out this tutorial http://bit.ly/15eACoY

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you need to change the Asterisk PBX port or Twinkle port. It is because both are listing on the same port. Make sure you are giving the secret in the configuration and also putting the same secret in Twinkle. Open the asterisk CLI using asterisk and make sure the registration request is reaching to the asterisk.

```
[1000]
type=friend
context=phones
host=dynamic
username=1000
secret=1000
```